# How to reformat result in graphql?

Tags: graphql

I have a query like this:

```
query GetProductsBySlug {
    categories(
    where:{slug: "pianos"}
  ) {
  products (first: 2) {
    id,
    slug,
    name,
    price,
    images(first: 1) {
      url
    }
  }
  }
}
```

Results from this query:

```
{
  "data": {
    "categories": [
      {
        "products": [
          {
          ...
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to remove "data":...", "categories":..., and only get this result:

```
{
        "products": [
          {
           ...
    }]

}
```

How I can do it?

I want that result only include {"products": ...} without data and categories.

Answer (score 0):

You can use just [destructuring assignment][1] and get just the categories like

```
const {data:{categories}} = queryResult;

and then map this categories array like
```

categories.map(category=> category.products)

```
  [1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment
```